# Print only a certain string in a line

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have a log containing error codes. I need to modify my script so it prints only the error codes, not the text immediately next to it.

```
egrep -e 'code\ [0-9]{2}' $error_file
```

This is the code that worked before. However, some error codes, apparently, in the logs, are now attached to the string, so I am forced to print those characters out as well.

Here is a copy of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Please enter input file name."
read input_variable
echo "You entered: $input_variable"

echo "Please enter a name of the new error file."
read error_file
touch $error_file
echo "The error file name is going to be $error_file"

echo "Processing printing only the error codes of ${input_variable} to ${error_file}."

egrep -e '\(code\ [0-9]{1,}\)' $input_variable | tee $input_variable.1 ;
awk '{print $12$13$14$15}' $input_variable.1 | tee $error_file ;

echo "Error Codes List: " ; 

egrep -e 'code[0-9]{2}' $error_file | sort -u ; 

echo "Common Errors - Count: "

echo "Code 2: " ; egrep -c 'code\ 2\)' $input_variable ;
echo "Code 10: " ; egrep -c 'code\ 10' $input_variable ;
echo "Code 11: " ; egrep -c 'code\ 11' $input_variable ;
echo "code 12: " ; egrep -c 'code\ 12' $input_variable ; 
echo "Code 14: " ; egrep -c 'code\ 14' $input_variable ;
echo "Code 20: " ; egrep -c 'code\ 20' $input_variable ;
echo "Code 23: " ; egrep -c 'code\ 23' $input_variable ; 
echo "Code 30: " ; egrep -c 'code\ 30' $input_variable ;
echo "Code 35: " ; egrep -c 'code\ 35' $input_variable ; 
echo "Total Files Transferred: " ; egrep -c '^\[[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}\ [0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\]' $input_variable ;
echo "Count Complete."
echo " " ;
echo "The following are details for each error:" ;
egrep -e 'code\ [0-9]{1,}' $input_variable ;
echo "Done. Thank you for using this error report" ;
rm $input_variable.1
```

Here is an example log:

```
[2015/12/09 06:52:10] [12.123.456.789] [email@address.com] [R] idevs error: error in idevs protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(1179) [sender=1.0.19]

[2015/12/09 03:01:05] [12.123.456.789] [email@address] [R] idevs error: timeout in data send/receive (code 30) at io.c(168) [sender=1.0.19]
```

My current output is:

```
Error Codes List: 
(code30)atio.c(168)
datastream(code12)
Common Errors - Count:
Code 2:
0
Code 10:
0
Code 11:
0
code 12:
63
Code 14:
0
Code 20:
0
Code 23:
0
Code 30:
11
Code 35:
0
Total Files Transferred:
263
Count Complete.

The following are details for each error:
//prints each line with code\ [0-9]{1,} in the line//
```

Please help me print the Error Codes List without the extra characters so it is just:

```
code12
code30
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want:

```
egrep -o 'code\ [0-9]{1,}' $input_variable | sort -u
```

It's the `-o` grep option that's the key here.

---

To find the totals, I'd rewrite your code so that you're only running grep once against that file:

```
count=()
total=0

while read code num; do
    (( count[$num]++, total++ ))
done < <(egrep -o 'code\ [0-9]+' $input_variable)

for num in 2 10 11 12 14 20 23 30 35; do 
    echo "Code $num: ${count[$num]}"
done
echo "Total: $total"
```

Comment: Something cool I would love to add to this would be to add the total number of errors. I don't see a way to do that at least with how I wrote the script. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I think that is a great idea. I entered your code in replacement of my total section. However, I got `./errors/script: line 32: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./errors/backerr1: line 32: `  done < <(egrep -o 'code\ [0-9]+' $input_variable)'` Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Oh yeah, my code is bash, so you have to change to `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: I changed it to `#!/usr/bash` and it works great! Thank you so much!